# How we test Delegate Scope Feature in android management api

Tags: delegates

I am not able to test this Delegate Scope Feature
https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#DelegatedScope
can anyone Help me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DPM.getDelegatedScopes(ComponentName, packageName)`. This will return the scopes assigned to the specific package.

If you want to test end-to-end, you may have to create a separate app with all those functionalities and then delegate the scope to your app.
I already did this for some of the delegations by creating a separate app.